# How to pass variable values in a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to hit a URL based on some variable data.

```
{
  this.state.countries.map((country, key) => {
    return <a key={country.iso2}>
      <img src="https://www.countryflags.io/{country.iso2}/shiny/24.png" />
    </a>;
  });
}
```

The value **{country.iso2}** in the above URL is dynamic.
Please help me to format the URL correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're working with jsx, you'll have to add the curly braces, then template literals and then the variable surrounded by `${}`, like so:

```js
let country = { iso2: "au" };
ReactDOM.render(
  <img src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${country.iso2}/shiny/24.png`} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Note use of `back tick` and `$`

```
<img src=`https://www.countryflags.io/${country.iso2}/shiny/24.png`/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
{this.state.countries.map((country, key) => {
       return
           <a key={country.iso2}>
               <img src=`https://www.countryflags.io/${country.iso2}/shiny/24.png`/>
                                </a>
 })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the backtick and dollar sign

```
{this.state.countries.map((country, key) => {
                            return
                                <a key={country.iso2}>
                                <img src=`https://www.countryflags.io/${country.iso2}/shiny/24.png`/>
                                </a>
 })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of doing is using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

If your value is dynamic then use of `back tick` and `$`